# How do I properly configure a Python Flask app to be served by Apache?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I've been trying to sort this out for ages but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Basically I want to use mod_wsgi with apache to serve my Python Flask app, what am I missing?

This is what I've got, a python flask app (flask_restful) with the a main.py as follows:

```
from app import create_app

application = create_app()

application.run(debug=True)
```

which calls my app.py

```
def create_app() -> Flask:

    errors = WWAPIErrors()
    errors.add_error(GeneralException, 400)

    app = Flask("namehere")
    api = WWAPI(error_list=errors, app=app)

    # APIS
    api.add_resource(endpointResouceClass, '/endpoint')

    return app
```

It all runs locally correctly, I have a VPS set up with other sites running perfectly but no python flask apps.

So I've done the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev

cd /var/www/appDirectory
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install mod_wsgi
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My website.conf file in the /etc/apache2/sites-available directory is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAdmin email@email.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/appDirectory/app/api/main.py
        DocumentRoot /var/www/appDirectory/app/api
        <Directory /var/www/appDirectory/app/api/main.py>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess localhost python-path=/var/www/appDirectory/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ user=www-data
        Alias /api /var/www/appDirectory/app/api

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Then I set my mod_wsgi config files:

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi

mod_wsgi-express module-config
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/user/appDirectory/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py310.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/home/user/appDirectory/venv"
```

and put that in my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.load file.

Next I enabled my site:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo a2ensite mysitename.conf
```

The directory of my project loads when I go to the base URL for my app because I have no index.html or anything on site.com/ root directory. But when I go to my implemented site url which is site.com/endpoint I just get a 404, I've even tried to get it locally on my VPS and no luck.

```
wget localhost:80/endpoint
--2022-12-08 21:07:15--  http://localhost/endpoint
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-12-08 21:07:15 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I know/hope I'm just missing something stupid, any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

System details:

```
neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: VMware Virtual Platform None 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 47 days, 10 hours, 49 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1392 (dpkg), 7 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1024x768 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2683 v3 (2) @ 1.997GHz 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   GPU: 00:0f.0 VMware SVGA II Adapter 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Memory: 987MiB / 1941MiB 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+                             
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/                              
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find my problem:

Apparently wsgi can't use main.py file directly. I needed to include an `app.wsgi` file in the root of my project directory, with the following contents:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/appDirectory/app/api')

from main import application
```

In addition to this I needed to edit my `main.py` file to remove the `application.run()` line as wsgi handles that itself. So my `main.py` file now looks like this:

```
from app import create_app

application = create_app()
```

Now when I run my application I no longer get a 404 but I get the correct response with a 200 code.

Hopefully this helps someone else at some stage, as I do think the information about mod_wsgi and wsgi is really lacking and conflicting online.